# How can I check my website is currently protect against csrf?

Tags: django, csrf

I am working on a dJango web and follow the tutorial to protect it against CSRF, I did something and not sure is it write now install or not, how can I see or check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/), to enable CSRF protection for your views, follow these steps:

1. Add the middleware `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` to your list of middleware classes, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your **settings.py**. (It should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.)
2. In any template that uses a **POST** form, use the `csrf_token` tag inside the  element if the form is for an internal URL, e.g.:

   ```
   <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   ```
3. In the corresponding view functions, ensure that the `'django.core.context_processors.csrf'` context processor is being used.

Following these steps will check that CSRF tokens are included properly.

By default, a **‘403 Forbidden’** response is sent to the user if an incoming request fails the checks performed by `CsrfViewMiddleware`. This should usually only be seen when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when, due to a programming error, the CSRF token has not been included with a POST form.

See the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for more info.

Comment: Thans, now after doing these how can I check my web is enabled its csrf?

Comment: Write a test, or physically submit your form. If you have followed the instructions in the docs, and you see no 403 error when the form is submitted, everything should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Check the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple in settings.py contains this

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

If this is there in the tuple , then csrf is installed.

Some like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```